# Bootstrapping vert.x from MainVerticle

Tags: java, vert.x

I've been playing with the various examples, and can't seem to find my way out of a weird corner. Based on the starter kit I got from vertx.io, MainVerticle is my entrypoint. Since I want to wire up some metrics, I do this;

```
  public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) {
    ...
    MetricsOptions metricsOptions = new MicrometerMetricsOptions()
      .setPrometheusOptions(new VertxPrometheusOptions().setEnabled(true))
      .setEnabled(true);
    VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions().setMetricsOptions(metricsOptions);
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions);

    DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions = new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(2);
    vertx.deployVerticle(ApiRootVerticle.class, deploymentOptions);
    ...
  }
```

So basically create my `VertxOptions`, create a new vertx instance, and deploy my Verticle. This throws a warning; `You're already on a Vert.x context, are you sure you want to create a new Vertx instance?`

I presume that I don't want a new instance (or do I?), so I was hunting for a way to use `Vertx.currentContext().owner()` since that's the root Vertx I'm running under. Not only can I not find a way to inject my `VertxOptions` into that, but I also can't deploy a verticle, as I get a new exception; `[ERROR] i.v.c.i.DeploymentManager - NULL (java.lang.NullPointerException: null)`

So the broad question is; how do I correctly bootstrap my code? More specifically, is that warning expected/normal? If not, how do I actually inject metrics and deploy verticles into the root Vertx?

Planning ahead, if I also want to use clustering, is the correct approach to use `main` and bootstrap from there? If I do so, can I still leverage the magic of gradle re-building and re-deploying on changes?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to start a Vert.x instance in your verticle:

`Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions);`

There are a few ways to control Vert.x starting options, but I suggest you just go old-school and start it yourself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MetricsOptions metricsOptions = new MicrometerMetricsOptions()
       .setPrometheusOptions(new VertxPrometheusOptions().setEnabled(true))
       .setEnabled(true);
    VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions().setMetricsOptions(metricsOptions);
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions);
    vertx.deployVerticle(new MainVerticle());
}
```